# Pandas mean function returns all NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, nan

I have this dataframe:

```
df = [{'A1':10, 'A2':''}, {'A1':11,'A2':110}, {'A1':12,'A2':120}]
```

And I'd like to average the different columns ignoring the '' (empty string) values.

This is the desired output

```
df_AVG = [{'A1':10, 'A2':'','avg':10}, {'A1':11,'A2':110,'avg': 60.5}, {'A1':12,'A2':120,'avg':66}]
```

And I can do it with this code:

```
df['avg'] = df[['A1','A2']].mean(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
```

But when I modify the dataframe and it includes **more than one** blank space, like this

```
df = [{'A1':10, 'A2':''}, {'A1':'','A2':110}, {'A1':12,'A2':120}]
```

And I run the same code, the output is this. All 'avg' values are NaN, including the ones that previously worked:

```
df_AVG = [{'A1':10, 'A2':'','avg':NaN}, {'A1':11,'A2':110,'avg': NaN}, {'A1':12,'A2':120,'avg':NaN}]
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with this approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use numeric_only it "drops" the not numerical columns, so in your second case, it drops all columns since they are both strings. If you check more closely your average on the first case you will see that in the second and third-row it only takes the 11 and 12 since the 110 and 120 are "dropped" because of the empty string.

If you want, you can do this:

`df['avg'] = df[['A1','A2']].replace('', np.nan).apply(lambda row: np.nanmean(row), axis=1)`

It replace '' with NaN and get the mean ignoring those NaN

Comment: I see, thank you! What would be your approach to skip blank spaces and average both columns with Pandas?

Comment: Just edited the post, see if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

You should coerce the columns to numeric types. A simple way could be:

```
df['avg'] = pd.DataFrame({col : pd.to_numeric(df[col]) for col in df.columns}).mean(axis=1)
```

It gives as expected:

```
   A1   A2    avg
0  10        10.0
1      110  110.0
2  12  120   66.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is also a useful approach which also worked, but I'll give Bruno Mello the solved answer because he answered first